# How to create a file name with current date & time in lua?

Tags: lua

I want to write a table into a file which named by the date and time it created.
I can open a file with hard coded name, write the table into it, like below:

```
FILENAME_EVENTS="Events.txt"            -- filename in string
local fp=io.open(FILENAME_EVENTS, a)        -- open a new file with the file name
io.output(FILENAME_EVENTS)      -- redirect the io output to the file
-- write the table into the file
for i, e in ipairs(eventlist) do io.write(e.title, e.category, e.ds, e.de, e.td) end
```

But when I try to:

```
FILENAME_EVENTS=os.date().."\.txt"          -- filename in string with date
local fp=io.open(FILENAME_EVENTS, a)        -- open a new file with the file name
io.output(FILENAME_EVENTS)      -- redirect the io output to the file
-- write the table into the file
for i, e in ipairs(eventlist) do io.write(e.title, e.category, e.ds, e.de, e.td) end
```

I got an error
 bad argument #1 to 'output' (10/06/11 17:45:01.txt: Invalid argument)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'output'

Why this "10/06/11 17:45:01.txt" is an invalid argument? due to it contains spaces or '/'? Or any other reasons?

BTW, the platform is win7 Pro + Lua 5.1.4 for win

Comment: What platform is this ? This shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 9):

Apparently it's both `/` and `:` that bork. The first probably because it is regarded as directory separator. This can be demonstrated as below:

```
fn=os.date()..'.txt'
print(io.open(fn,'w')) -- returns invalid argument

fn=os.date():gsub(':','_')..'.txt'
print(io.open(fn,'w')) -- returns nil, no such file or directory

fn=os.date():gsub('[:/]','_')..'.txt'
print(io.open(fn,'w')) -- returns file(0x...), nil <-- Works
```

BTW, instead of using strange gsub and concatenation tricks, you might also consider using something like

```
fn=os.date('%d_%m_%y %H_%M.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks jpjacobs, it works. Sorry I can't vote for yr answer since I don't have 15 reputation points :(